# Why does scan upcast?

Tags: python, theano

This code to calculate the trace of a matrix (based on an example in the Theano "loop" tutorial) works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as T
floatX = 'float32'
X = T.matrix()
results = th.scan(lambda i,j,t_f : T.cast(X[i,j] + t_f, floatX),
                      sequences=[T.arange(X.shape[0]), T.arange(X.shape[1])],
                      outputs_info=np.asarray(0., dtype=floatX))[0]
result = results[-1]
compute_trace = th.function([X], result)
x = np.eye(5, dtype=floatX)
x[0] = np.arange(5, dtype=floatX)
print compute_trace(x)
```

But if I remove the cast operation from the lambda function like this:

```
lambda i,j,t_f : X[i,j] + t_f
```

The following error message is produced:

ValueError: When compiling the inner function of scan the following error has been encountered: The initial state (`outputs_info` in scan nomenclature) of variable IncSubtensor{Set;:int64:}.0 (argument number 2) has dtype float32, while the result of the inner function (`fn`) has dtype float64. This can happen if the inner function of scan results in an upcast or downcast.

Why so? `X` and `outputs_info` are explicitly set to float32. How does the result of adding them get to be float64?

Comment: I don't know why but you can try `theano.config.floatX = 'float32'` instead.

Comment: Thanks - works great, and much clearer. Seems like it must be that scan() uses typed internals that we don't see. Hopefully we'll get an expert explanation.

Comment: yes, I guess so, and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but we're working on a fork of Theano called [Aesara](https://github.com/aesara-devs/aesara), and, since people still run into problems like this, it seems worthwhile to provide a public explanation.

That said, the issue is `X = T.matrix()`.  `T.matrix` creates a float64 matrix when `theano.config.floatX == "float64"` (the default), and the result is an upcast to float64 for the sum in the body of the `scan`'s loop function.

If `X = T.fmatrix()` is used, a float32 matrix is created instead and the problem is no longer present; otherwise, as mentioned in the comments, one can also set `theano.config.floatX` to `"float32"`.